# matplotlib の ylimについて　下限値は指定、上限値は自動にしたい

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

以下のコードについて質問させてください。
左のグラフのy軸を変更したいと考えており
左のグラフから右のグラフへ変更しようとしておりました。

y軸の変更方法ですが

y軸のyminが0,ymaxは自動調整してほしいのですが、
yminは0になったのですが、ymaxがなぜだか1.0になってしまいます。
どうコードを記載したらよいのかわかりません。
すみませんが、ご教授お願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
#散布図作成
plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))

#左のグラフ作成
fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.title('そり推移　グラフ', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('',fontsize=20)
plt.xlim([-0.5,8]) #X軸調整
plt.ylabel('',fontsize=20)

sns.regplot(jpn_x, jpn_y,
        data=jpn_df,
        order=1,
        line_kws={'color':'indianred'})

#右のグラフ作成
fig.add_subplot(1,2,2,xlabel='x') 

#軸調整
plt.xlabel('',fontsize=20)
plt.xlim(-1.5,8) #X軸調整
plt.ylabel('',fontsize=20)
plt.ylim(0,) #Y軸調整
#plt.ylim(ymin=0) #Y軸調整

plt.title('そり推移　グラフ', fontsize=20)
sns.regplot(jpn_x, jpn_y,
        data=jpn_df,
        order=1,
        line_kws={'color':'indianred'})
```

matplotlib ver
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
matplotlibのバージョン確認したのですがおそらく最新でした。

```
Requirement already up-to-date: matplotlib in 
c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (3.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cycler>=0.10 in 
c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) 
(0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy>=1.10.0 in 
c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) 
(1.14.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: 
pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in 
c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) 
(2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in 
c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) 
(1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil>=2.1 in 
c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) 
(2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in 
c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in 
c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib) (39.1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ylim`は、`plt`で設定するのではなくて、`seaborn`の方で最後に設定する必要があると思われます。

```
#軸調整
plt.xlabel('',fontsize=20)
plt.xlim(-1.5,8) #X軸調整
plt.ylabel('',fontsize=20)

plt.title('そり推移　グラフ', fontsize=20)
rp = sns.regplot(jpn_x, jpn_y,
        data=jpn_df,
        order=1,
        line_kws={'color':'indianred'})
rp.axes.set_ylim(0,)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘頂いた方法を用いたのですが、グラフの表示が変わりませんでした。

    `bottom, top = plt.ylim()`     
    `plt.ylim(bottom,top) #Y軸調整`  

色々試したのですが、上記コードに変えても同じグラフができてしまいました。

Comment: matplotlibのバージョン確認したのですがおそらく最新でした。

Comment: seaborn の方で設定しないといけないかもしれないですね。

Comment: 私の方でも、plt.ylim(0,)とするとymaxは1になりました。回答を変更したので確認してください。

Comment: 回答頂いた方法にしたところ改善しました。
seabornの方でも設定できたのですね。

ありがとうございました。感謝します。